# solr atomic updating via URL

Tags: solr

How do I perform an update to my solr table using a basic http request? I can pull data using something like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/database/select?q=id:6686
```

But what if I want to change a record that is already in the system?  I have found some documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents), that claims I should be able to do something that's equivalent to this:

`update solr set name = 'brian' where id = 6686`, but I cannot find anything on a URL to call to do this... something like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/database/update?q=id:6686&set=name:brian
```

I'm using solr 5.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script that solves this.  I hope this is useful for someone else in the future...

```
function solr_update( $id, $value ) {
  $ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update?commit=true");

  $data = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "user_name" => array(
              "set" => $value),
            );

  $data_string = json_encode(array($data));          

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
  curl_exec($ch);

}


solr_update($id, $value);
```

In this example, if I set `$id = 20522` and `$value = "Brian"`, the `solr_update` function will set the `user_name` field to `Brian` where the `id` is `20522`.

Answer (score 0):

Solr is able to perform atomic updates since its 5.1 version I believe. A complete example covering both update over http and SolrJ can be found [here](http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/). Moreover, please notice that:

1. The field named as id in the example, must be replaced with your unique key (check your schema.xml) and
2. If you're looking for some more specific use case, dig more stackoverflow questions as there are many relevant.

Comment: I've looked through every tutorial I could find online, as well as every stackoverflow question I could find, and I couldn't find any information on doing this.  The examples that yonik gives use cURL at (what appears to be) the command line, which won't work for me.  I was wondering if there was a way to update similarly to using the `select` statement.

Comment: any idea how to do this using PHP and cURL?